# How to redirect to an html page? My onclick is not firing

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

So I have a start.html that allows you to select how many players you want to play and add their names into an input.
I am trying to grab that input and place it into the innerHTML of the index pager which is where a user selects truth or dare to start the game. The button click for the btnStart refuses to switch to the index.html.

here is my play.js

```
function readyPlayer(){
var input1 = document.getElementById("player1Name");
sessionStorage.setItem("player1", input1.value());

var player1Text = sessionStorage.getItem("player1");
document.getElementById('playerText').innerHTML = player1Text + ", you're up!";
location.href = 'index.html';
```

}

Here is my start.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Truth or Dare</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<div style="font-size: 20px;">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md navigation-clean" style="background: rgb(4,2,2);">
        <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="border-color: rgb(10,10,10);color: rgb(247,242,242);">Truth or Dare</a><button data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navcol-1"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span></button>
            <div
                class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto"></ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <h1 class="text-center" style="margin-top: 100px;">How many players are going to play?</h1>
    <div class="text-center" style="height: 50px;padding-top: 0px;margin: 0;margin-top: 50px;border-style: none;">
        <button id="btn1" onclick="select1Player();" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="height: 50px;width: 100px;background: rgb(7,1,1);border-style: none;">1</button>
        <button id="btn2" onclick="select2Player();" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="height: 50px;width: 100px;background: rgb(8,12,16);margin-left: 40px;border-style: none;">2</button>
        <button id="btn3" onclick="select3Player();" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="height: 50px;width: 100px;background: rgb(8,12,16);margin-left: 40px;border-style: none;">3</button>
        <button id="btn4" onclick="select4Player();" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="height: 50px;width: 100px;background: rgb(8,12,16);margin-left: 40px;border-style: none;">4</button>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 50px;">
        <h1 id="playerText" class="text-center" style="font-size: 30px;margin-top: 30px;display:none;">Enter the player's name(s)</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="player1Div" class="text-center" style="height: 50px;margin-top: 1px;display:none;">
        <h3 class="text-center d-inline-block" style="margin-right: 15px;display:none;">Player 1:</h3>
        <input id="player1Name" type="text"></div>
    <div id="player2Div" class="text-center" style="height: 50px;margin-top: 1px;display:none;">
        <h3 class="d-inline-block" style="margin-right: 15px;">Player 2:</h3>
        <input id="player2Name" type="text"></div>
    <div id="player3Div" class="text-center" style="height: 50px;margin-top: 1px;display:none;">
        <h3 class="d-inline-block" style="margin-right: 15px;">Player 3:</h3>
        <input id="player3Name" type="text"></div>
    <div id="player4Div" class="text-center" style="height: 50px;margin-top: 1px;display:none;">
        <h3 class="d-inline-block" style="margin-right: 15px;">Player 4:</h3>
        <input id="player4Name" type="text"></div>
    <div id="divStart" class="text-center" style="height: 50px; margin-top: 1px;display:none;">
    <input id="btnStart" onclick="readyPlayer();" type="button" value="Start" class="btn btn-primary" style="height: 50px;width: 150px;background: rgb(8,12,16);margin-left: 40px;border-style: none;"></input>
    </div>
    <script src="player.js"></script>
    <script src="play.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Truth or Dare</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md navigation-clean" style="background: rgb(4,2,2);">
        <div class="container"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="border-color: rgb(10,10,10);color: rgb(247,242,242);">Truth or Dare</a>
            <button data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggler" data-target="#navcol-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div
                class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navcol-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto"></ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Buttons for selecting truth or dare OnClick -->
    <h1 class="text-center" style="margin-top: 150px;">Player, you're up!</h1>
    <div class="text-center" onclick="location.href='truth.html'" style="height: 50px;padding-top: 0px;margin-top: 50px;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="height: 50px;width: 230px;background: rgb(8,12,16);">TRUTH</button>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 50px;">
        <h1 class="text-center">or</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center" onclick="location.href='dare.html'" style="height: 50px;margin-top: 5px;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="height: 50px;width: 230px;background: rgb(7,1,1);">DARE</button>
    </div>
    <script src="player.js"></script>
    <script src="play.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think you have `.value()` instead of `.value`.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to make it work by using:

```js
location.href = '/index.html';
// or
window.location.href = '/index.html';
```

instead of:

```js
location.href = 'index.html';
```

Might have something to do with it being a relative route?

Answer (score 0):

- Above reply did answer the question, anytime anything wrong with JavaScript first check the console for any obvious errors withing JavaScript (browser compatability issue).
- On a sidebar approach in past when I had java script issue,I added an anchor tag <a href, instead of button ( changed the anchor's style to look like button ). If it helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do this would be to store it as a variable in the URL, but you seem to be using a local file, so I'm not 100% sure if that works.

The next way I can think of is cake- no, cookies. Here's some important pieces of code **directly copy and pasted from w3schools at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp . I did not create any of this code.**

```js
//This returns a cookie with the name equal to the parameter cname
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}




//sets a cookie named the first parameter with the value of the second parameter lasting the third parameter long
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

Comment: I see that you downvoted this, how could I have better assisted you?